# Chromium Cast function does not find the chromecast device

Tags: chromium, chromecast

I am using Chromium version 80.0.3987.100 snap 64 bits in both 19.10 and 18.04. Both computers do not find the chromecast device. I tried to use mkchromecast but it cannot find the device either.

I tried to enable:
chrome://flags/#media-router 
chrome://flags/#media-router-cast-allow-all-ips

but still the chromium cannot find any devices.
Both computers are connected to the same WIFI. But i am wondering, how can the chromecast device connect to a WIFI without any authentication? Could be this the problem?
It LED in the chromecast is blinking white which means it needs to be configure. Google says that it is only possible to configure it using the Google Home app which does not install in my phone because i have android 4.2 and apparently only install in android 4.4
How can i make the configuration and make it run?
Thank you.

Comment: One bad thing about chromecast is that it has to be configured with an Android device, phone or tablet(any bodies), so you can have a friend do it.  Once it is configured it should work well, at least with chrome, not tried chromium.  Also make sure permissions for chromium are given in software store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give up. I use a android device to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking online for this issue howto fix. Maybe a little bit late, but for me these these three flags on enabled work.

- Connect to Cast devices on all IP addresses
- Global media controls control Cast start/stop
- Enable Open Screen Library (libcast) as the Mirroring Service's Cast  Streaming implementation

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable the flags load-media-router-component-extension
If that doesn't work after a relaunch, you may also need to enable cast-media-route-provider

Unfortunately without a device that can confirm if the chromecast has been properly configured, it isn't possible to determine if the issue is with your chromium flags or the chromecast itself.

Chrome-stable will have all the required flags enabled by default and should allow you actually set up the chromecast, see https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-google-chrome-web-browser-on-ubuntu-18-04/ for instructions on Ubuntu.
Good luck!